# How to disable jtable checkbox based on the other column data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have jtable with col1 checkbox field and col2 text area. My requirement is to disable the  col1 checkbox field based on the condition of the col2 and this needs to be done during the layout out the table.

Comment: Please provide some code which you have done and if you are facing an error then update your question too.

Comment: add some code effort here that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is to disable the col1 checkbox field based on the condition of the col2

Override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the `JTable`.

Instead of just returning true/false for the checkbox column you will need to text the data in column 2 to decide if the checkbox should be editable.